# Python code to ignore errors

Tags: python

I have a code that stops running each time there is an error.
Is there a way to add a code to the script which will ignore all errors and keep running the script until completion?

Below is the code:

```
import sys
import tldextract

def main(argv):

        in_file = argv[1]
        f = open(in_file,'r')
        urlList = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        destList = []

        for i in urlList:
            print i
            str0 = i
            for ch in ['\n','\r']:
                    if ch in str0:
                        str0 = str0.replace(ch,'')
            str1 = str(tldextract.extract(str0))

            str2 = i.replace('\n','') + str1.replace("ExtractResult",":")+'\n'
            destList.append(str2)

        f = open('destFile.txt','w')
        for i in destList:
                f.write(i)

        f.close()

        print "Completed successfully:"


if __name__== "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Many thanks

Comment: Sure, just use try/except statements

Comment: Where is your error happening?

Comment: I find the mindset of "let's just ignore errors and just keep plowing forward" very troubling. At the very least you'll have to be picky about what errors you *can* safely ignore and what to fall back to instead.

Comment: Your question starts from the wrong premise. You should **not** ignore errors, you should perhaps handle them.

Comment: To put it another way: *"I want to walk down the road, I fell on my face, how do I ignore the pain and simply keep moving my legs until I have reached the end of the road?"* – You probably shouldn't.

Comment: @deceze: *I want to drive down the road in my car, the road is uneven and I  drove into the first pothole breaking the suspension and I want to keep going through all the other potholes* :D

Comment: I am not a programmer, and new to Python, so if you think my question is stupid you can just ignore it.
This code was built to help me analyze millions of domains. So one domain with wrong syntax can stop the entire thing. I just want this to keep running because I don't care about fixing each of these million domains.
Thank you for your time (and sarcasm)

Answer (score 3):

You should always 'try' to open files. This way you can manage exceptions, if the file does not exist for example. Take a loot at [Python Tutorial Exeption Handling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)

```
import sys

try:
    f = open('myfile.txt')
    s = f.readline()
    i = int(s.strip())
except IOError as e:
    print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
except ValueError:
    print "Could not convert data to an integer."
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    raise
```

or

```
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    try:
        f = open(arg, 'r')
    except IOError:
        print 'cannot open', arg
    else:
        print arg, 'has', len(f.readlines()), 'lines'
        f.close()
```

Do not(!) just 'pass' in the exception block. This will(!) make you fall on your face even harder.

Comment: This is a good example to show the usage of the `with` statement: `with open('myfile.txt') as f:`. Look at the last example of "[Methods of File Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)" in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Where ever your error(s) is happening you can wrap it in a try/except block

```
for i in loop:
    try:
        code goes here...
    except:
        pass
```